# Express Gateway - Is data composition/aggregation possible?

Tags: node.js, express, gateway

I've been reading a lot but don't seem to find an answer to the question:

Is it possible to do data composition, for example from 3 microservices? => Exposing an endpoint with the aggregate data on the API Gateway?

Or how does one approach this? I thought this was basic behaviour desired from a API Gateway?

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for a little bit more, maybe with an example? If you're asking if you can pull data from multiple different sources and combine them to send back via a route endpoint, then your answer is yes.